# How to determine the wordsize in Linux kernel programming?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, architecture, programming

In userspace code, the macro `__WORDSIZE` is used, included in `<bits/wordsize.h>`. However, when I do Linux kernel programming, the `__WORDSIZE` seems not available.

If `<bits/wordsize.h>` is included, it will receive a compile error, saying:

```
error: bits/wordsize.h: No such file or directory
```

but if `<bits/wordsize.h>` is not included, it will receive another compile error, saying:

```
error: ‘__WORDSIZE’ undeclared.
```

It seems that kernel programming doesn't support the `<bits/wordsize.h>` header file. What should I do to determine the wordsize in Linux kernel programming?

P.S. my compiler version is `gcc (GCC) 4.4.6`.

Comment: As this is very specifically about programming, i voted to move to SO. However, out of interest, why such an old version of gcc?

Comment: The gcc's version depends on my company's willing.

Comment: That's deeply unfortunate. It's now 5 minor releases behind…

Comment: @HalosGhost I am also very annoyed about it, because many new features are not available.

Comment: The `asm/types.h` should have `BITS_PER_LONG` set, which should be the word size to [Robert Love's *Linux Kernel Development*](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=3MWRMYRwulIC&pg=PT595&lpg=PT595&dq=kernel+word+size&source=bl&ots=2ajFtbvblf&sig=Dqejk39Lmq8Elin_btA-p-szYto&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XsJkVLbENY6yuATRpoLgDw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=kernel%20word%20size&f=false) (sixth result in the search).